# How can I average one row of every two columns in Excel?

Tags: excel, offset

[image: screenshot table]

Hi, I have a large dataset where I need to calculate a lot of averages. I have a large table, where every row represents a different timepoint, and every two adjacent columns are a replicate of that timepoint, which I want to calculate the average of and return it in a new table below. Basically, I want to calculate the average of the same row of two columns (i.e. C55 and D55), and put the averages in C92, then move on to the next set of two columns (i.e. E55 to and F55), put the averages in D92 and so on.

I have tried using the Offset formula, but I can't figure it out. Could someone provide me with the correct formula to plug in?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Why offset()?  I would enter "=average(C55,D55)" in cell C92, then copy and paste into E92 etc. Using D92 causes a shift that is harder to work with.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365 you could use this formula in `C92` to retrieve the averages for row 55:

`=TOROW(BYROW(WRAPROWS(C55:H55,2),LAMBDA(r,AVERAGE(r))))`

`WRAPWROWS` wraps the row into single rows per two columns - then it is easy to calculate the average 'BYROW'.